# Froala set text size in the beginning

Tags: php, jquery, froala

Using the Froala text Editor, How can I set programatically the initial size of text? it's blocked to 28px and cannot be modified by a simple option.

```
$('#editorAsunto').editable({ // idioma también cargando el es.js 
        inlineMode: false, language: 'es', maxCharacters: 1000,
        placeholder: 'Escribe el asunto del mensaje. Hasta 1000 caracteres...', 
        heightMin: 60, heightMax: 100, height: 60,
        buttons: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strikeThrough","sep"
                       ,"fontFamily", "fontSize", "formatBlock", "color","sep"
                       ,"insertOrderedList", "insertUnorderedList", "outdent", "indent", "sep"
                       ,"createLink", "insertHorizontalRule", "table","html"]
         });
```

The option ***fontSizeDefaultSelection: '14'*** doesn't do the trick.

```
$('#editorAsunto').froalaEditor({  fontSizeDefaultSelection: '14' });
```

Must I change css froala styling in any way? Thanks.

Comment: For using `fontSizeDefaultSelection` option you should include `font_family.min.js` extension with your code. Do you ?

Comment: Found a solution! You only need to style the div container where FROALA is! css font-size property does the trick!!!! Thanks everybody. I was stuck on this nonsense.